# why the sql correct and the inner mechanism for run it?

Tags: mysql, sql

the sql as follows come from [mysql document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparisons-using-subqueries.html). it is:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 AS t
  WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id);
```

The document say *It finds all rows in table t1 containing a value that occurs twice in a given column* , and doesnot explain the sql.

t1 and t is the same table, so the

> `count(*) in subquery  == select count(*) from t`

, isn't it?

Comment: your question is unclear ! Please edit your question to give your table schema, sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
count(*) in subquery  == select count(*) from t
```

is wrong. because in mysql you can't use it like that. so you have to run it like that to get result of same id having two rows.

if you want to get count of same occurrence,

```
SELECT id, name, count(*) AS all_count FROM t1 GROUP BY id HAVING all_count > 1 ORDER BY all_count DESC
```

And also you can get values as your query like this as well,

```
select * from t1 where id in ( select id from t1 group by id having count(*) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The query contains a *correlated subquery* in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id
```

It is called *correlated* because it is related to the main query via `t.id`. So, this subquery counts the number of records having an `id` value that is equal to the current `id` value of the record returned by the main query.

Thus, predicate

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id) = 2
```

evaluates to `true` for any row with an `id` value that occurs twice in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 AS t
  WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id);
```

This query goes through each record in t1 and then in the subquery looks into t1 again to see if in this case `id` is found 2 times (and only 2 times). You can do the same for any other column in t1 (or any table for that matter).

When you would like to see all values that are multiple times in the table, change `WHERE 2 =` by `WHERE 1 <`. This will also give you the values that are 3 times, 4 times, etc. in the table.

Answer (score 1):

{
SELECT id,count( * )
FROM 
MyTable 
group by id
having count( * )>1
}

with this code, you can see the rows which repet more than one,
and you can change this query by yourself

Answer (score 0):

How about using GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
SELECT id, count(1) as Total FROM MyTable AS t1
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING Total = 2
```

Comment: This will not return the same results as it doesn't return all columns.